# Braintree payment validation

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox, braintree-data

Currently i am using braintree hosted fields for a project.Its integrated successfully. but what if the user remove the card details after recieving the payment method nonce token. is there any callback for validate in such a case ?
I tried onError function but its not working after recieving payment method nonce token.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Not sure, but it sounds like you’re asking what happens if the user deletes the card after Hosted Fields tokenizes the card; If the user removes the card information after the tokenization process, it doesn’t matter--- the card is already tokenized. This shouldn’t be caught in the `onError` function, as this isn’t an error. It's just a change in what occupies the UI in the DOM.